# proftpd no directory listing after activating TLS

Tags: firewall, ftp, ssl, tls, proftpd

I'm running proftpd on Ubuntu 18.x and activated TLS. Ports range for passive mode are open by ufw. 
Still, when TLS is activated in the proftpd config, directory listing fails.

What could be the reason?

When TLS is deactivated, directory listing is working fine.

Firewall status:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
49152:65534/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
49152:65534/udp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
49152:65534/tcp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
49152:65534/udp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

ProFTPd Config for ports:

```
Port                            21
PassivePorts                  49152 65534
```

TLS Protcol

```
TLSProtocol                             SSLv23
```

Comment: Please check the logs of proftpd for errors and if possible turn on debug/verbose information in your unknown FTP client. If you see `client did not reuse SSL session, rejecting data connection` in the servers log set the NoSessionReuseRequired  parameter. See [proftpd TLS HOWTO](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/TLS.html) for more, specifically the FAQ part.

Comment: @steffen-ullrich This lead to the solution. I posted an answer, but please add your solution as votable post. Otherwise you get no acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

Activating the following option in tls.conf was successful:

```
TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired
```

Thanks to @steffen-ullrich

Comment: I do feel that your answer must have more supportive illustrations !! Better [Edit your post](https://superuser.com/questions/1464466/edit) and add useful text, also Thanks should press through comments !!